# 'str' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to replace gas with `1` and diesel with `0` but not able to do that and getting below error:

> AttributeError: `str` object has no attribute `map`

code:

```
carprice['fueltype']=carprice['fueltype'].apply(lambda x: x.map({'gas':1,'diesel':0}))
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :-

```
carprice['fueltype']=carprice['fueltype'].map({'gas':1,'diesel':0})
```

or you can do

```
carprice['fueltype']=carprice['fueltype'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x =='gas' else 0))
```

Map basically operates on the series while apply works on each cell.

Comment: how to make it case insensitive like in some rows the 'fueltype' maybe 'Gas' or 'Diesel'

Answer (score 2):

Map function with in "apply" works fine if your column is of dataframe type rather than a series.
To convert a column from series to dataframe enclose it with in '[]'

```
carprice[['fueltype']]=carprice[['fueltype']].apply(lambda x: x.map({'gas':1,'diesel':0}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Series.map(arg, na_action=None)[source]
Map values of Series according to input correspondence.
```

Used for substituting each value in a Series with another value, that may be derived from a function, a dict or a Series.

But when you are applying a lambda function and trying to map the values of the column, it's taking it as a string instead of Series.

Therefore to make it consider as series you have to enclose the column in square brackets like below:

```
carprice['fueltype'] = carprice['fueltype'] \
                       .apply(lambda x: x.map({'gas':1,'diesel':0}))
```

Or you can use it as below without the lambda function:

```
varlist =  ['fueltype']
    def binary_map(x):
        return x.map({'gas':1,'diesel':0})
carprice[varlist] = carprice[varlist].apply(binary_map)
```

Both the approaches work absolutely fine.

**The only thing to note is that we should pass a series to map function.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

PyhtonCode: `df['Response'] = df['Response'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x =='Yes' or x == 'yes' else( 0 if x =='No' or x == 'No' else 0.5))`

or

```
df['Response'] = df['Response'].map({'Yes': 1, 'No' : 0, 'Maybe': 0.5,' yes': 1, 'no' : 0, 'maybe': 0.5})
```

Following is the reference link.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/